# Python multiprocessing behavior for large arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I encountered an interesting feature/bug for python multiprocessing, and wondered if anybody can offer deeper insights. I create a numpy array via `np.arange` inside a function and add a constant to it. If the array length is less than circa <100k items, this works well. However, if the array is longer, the multiprocessing crashes without error warning and gets stuck. Example code:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing


#::: works well
# def fct(arg):
#     a,b = arg
#     x = a + np.arange(-0.25*b, 0.75*b, 0.01) #small array, sum outside
#     print(len(x), np.mean(x))

#::: works well
# def fct(arg):
#     a,b = arg
#     x = np.arange(a-0.25*b, a+0.75*b, 0.001) #large array, sum inside
#     print(len(x), np.mean(x))

#::: crashes with pool
# def fct(arg):
#     a,b = arg
#     x = a + np.arange(-0.25*b, 0.75*b, 0.001) #large array, sum outside
#     print(len(x), np.mean(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(np.random.normal(2458000,100,size=10), np.random.normal(200,10,size=10))]

    #::: loop
    print('\n loop:')
    for arg in args:
        fct(arg)

    # ::: pool
    print('\n pool:')
    with closing(Pool(processes=(2))) as pool:
        pool.map(fct, args)
```

Comment: could it be a memory error? does it happen the same if processes = 10 for example? it works for me without error and i get the print

Comment: Thanks Victor, this happens the same way for processes = 10 or other numbers. I also assume it is a memory error, but I do not understand why "a + np.arange" causes the crash, while "np.arange(a+)" is fine.